# jQuery Sparklines vertical bullet

Tags: jquery, sparklines

Does anyone know how to make [jQuery Sparklines](http://www.omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#s-about) displaying vertical? like this http://screencast.com/t/M2fQaKPW

May be you can advise some other plugin with similar data displaying?

Thanks!